# Missing client_id parameter.on heroku rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth

I am trying to authenticate user to rails 6 app using omniauth.  It works locally but when I deployed to heroku I was getting an error saying invalid id.

I looked around and found a post about updating the gem from just omniauth-facebook to gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0', so I did that and now it just goes back to the home page without logging in locally and on heroku I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101,
      "fbtrace_id": "AYAEC-EyMzZgNXYS2L9klkw"
   }
}
```

I set my credentials in the credentials.yml file:

```
facebook:
  facebook_client_id: 1234123412341234
  facebook_client_secret: 12345123451234512345
```

My devise.rb file is:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Rails.application.credentials.dig(:facebook, :facebook_client_id),
  Rails.application.credentials.dig(:facebook, :facebook_client_secret), scope: 'public_profile,email', info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, picture'
```

If you need to see any other code let me know and I will edit the question.

Comment: I'd try replacing `facebook_client_id` with `client_id` and `facebook_client_secret` with `client_secret` in your credentials file and devise.rb file.

Comment: I tried that but stil the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `credentials.yml` is in `.gitignore` file, try adding the credentials in heroku `config vars`.

Comment: I added client_id and client_secret but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it working completely fine locally or are you having any errors?

Comment: It was but whenIupgraded the gem it stopped but I went back to the older one and it still isn't working.  I don't get an error, it just goes back to the home page and doesn't log me in.  I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: did you add the credentials in ENV variables? like ENV['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_KEY']

Comment: NO, I folowed a video and he had me add them to the credentials.yml file.  Where and how woud I do it that way. Sorry, I'm new to al this.

Comment: you need to add ENV variable in `devise.rb` like this `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOKCLIENT_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET']` also can you share the link of the video you are following?

Comment: This is what I have in my devise.rb file:  config.omniauth :facebook, Rails.application.credentials.dig(:facebook, :client_id),
  Rails.application.credentials.dig(:facebook, :client_secret), scope: 'public_profile,email', info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, picture'

Comment: if that doesn't work try adding the the `client_key` and `client_secret` directly to `devise.rb` and if that works then use a gem like `figaro` to hide credentials

Comment: Here is the video I followed.  You have advice on a better way to set this up I am happy to start over with this part.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd8dOAL6WYs&t=2814s

Comment: here are some resources that might be helpful https://dev.to/nkemjiks/implementing-facebook-authentication-with-devise-for-your-rails-6-app-1p3b   https://medium.com/@chinnatiptaemkaeo/integrate-omniauth-facebook-to-rails-5-1389d760d92a

Comment: Ok, I started over and now the site doesn't crash on heroku which is a plus. It works locally but on heroku I get the error: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
The localhost redirect url is localhost:3000/facebook_signup but that doens't work on heroku so I added the url inthe error https://the-mat-house.herokuapp.com/users/facebook/callback but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I guess I had a typo in my redirect url but I got it working.  Thanks you so much for all your help!